# ASP.NET: TreeView CurrentNodeStyle missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, treeview

Is there a CurrentNodeStyle set of properties in the ASP.NET version of the TreeView, or am I just blind?  I want to set the CssClass for whichever node the user is currently on, and I'm not seeing a way to do this.

Googling reveals there was such a beast in classic ASP, but I'm trying to use ASP.NET 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think SelectedNodeStyle is what you're looking for. :)